# Nullable int type allowed in Settings.settings?

Tags: c#

I have a property that I'd like to type as `int?` in my Settings.settings file.  When I use `int?` I get a runtime failure:

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object..

I can use a string type as a workaround where a check for null works, but I have to parse the string and handle errors when the parse doesn't work.

Being able to set the value to null allows me to keep the property documented in the settings file while making it obvious that no value has been set.  When not set I use a programmed default value:

```
int? configuredNumberOfLimits = Settings.Default.RequiredNumberOfLimits;
if ( configuredNumberOfLimits == null  )
{
    requiredNumberOfLimits = DEFAULT_REQUIRED_NUMBER_LIMITS;
}
```

Comment: @Gage: I think that's missing the point. He wants the setting *defined* as an `int?`.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

There is a way to use nullable type (i.e. `int?`) for a setting - it requires a bit of manual editing of the settings file, but afterwards works fine in VS environment and in the code. And requires no additional functions or wrappers.

To do this, create a setting with desired name (e.g. *RequiredNumberOfLimit*) and make it of any type (e.g. standard `int` for convenience).
Save the changes.

Now go to your project folder and open the "Properties\Settings.settings" file with text editor (Notepad, for example) Or you can open it in VS by right-clicking in Solution Explorer on "<Your Project> -> Properties -> Settings.settings", select "Open With..." and then choose either "XML Editor" or "Source Code (Text) Editor".
In the opened xml settings find your setting (it will look like this):

```
<Setting Name="RequiredNumberOfLimit" Type="System.Int32" Scope="User">
  <Value Profile="(Default)">0</Value>
</Setting>
```

Change the "Type" param from `System.Int32` to `System.Nullable<System.Int32>`. And also clear the default value (so null could be used there by default).
Now this section should look like this (note that `&lt;` and `&gt;` are used to represent `<` and `>` symbols inside the type string  - this is done for correct parsing of xml by VS):

```
<Setting Name="RequiredNumberOfLimit" Type="System.Nullable&lt;System.Int32&gt;" Scope="User">
  <Value Profile="(Default)" />
</Setting>
```

Now save changes and re-open project settings - voilà! - we have the setting *RequiredNumberOfLimit* with type `System.Nullable<System.Int32>` which is parsed correctly by VS Settings Designer, as well as it could be used as a normal `int?` variable in the code.

If you want this setting to be able to return `null` you should keep the default value field clear.
Otherwise, the default value will be returned by this setting if it was assigned to null previously (but thats how the default values work, don't they? :P).

Comment: The approach worked for viewing the setting in the Settings designer and for setting the default value in code. However, my setting disappeared from the App.config file when I made this change. That may or may not be important in a given context, but I thought it was worth noting.

Comment: To add to what @Brian said: yes, editing with the Settings designer will wipe out the settings from app.config, but if you put them back, they are read from there again. So, either don't use the designer, or remember to put the settings back after using it... kind of a pain, but in my case I think it's worth it.

Comment: Settings Designer in VS 2019 doesn't seem to have any issue with the nullable type, and even adds it to the drop-down list of types.

Comment: @ThomasS.Trias, yay, 9 years later they finally add it to the VS designer :) Thanks for letting us know, though.

Answer (score 4):

I think your best bet is going to be an old-fashioned `bool`/`int` combo. It isn't the prettiest solution, but it's not really all *that* different from an `int?`.

```
int configuredNumberOfLimits;
if (Settings.Default.HasRequiredNumberOfLimits)
{
    configuredNumberOfLimits = Settings.Default.RequiredNumberOfLimits;
}
else
{
    configuredNumberOfLimits = DEFAULT_REQUIRED_NUMBER_LIMITS;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Since int? isn't a supported type in Settings.settings my choice seems to be between what you've suggested and what @Kevin suggests.

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
int configuredNumberOfLimits

if(!int.TryParse(Settings.Default.RequiredNumberOfLimits, 
    out configuredNumberOfLimits))
{
   configuredNumberOfLimits = DEFAULT_REQUIRED_NUMBER_LIMITS;
}
```

This way you can check the value, and if it fails you set the default value.  No worries about strings or parsing, or un-handled exceptions.

Comment: That's the workaround I mentioned.  I'd like to avoid the parse if possible.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but did you try int? value = Settings... as (int)

Answer (score 1):

You can manual set type in Settings.Designer.cs

For instance:

```
    public decimal? Test{
        get {
            return ((decimal?)(this["Test"]));
        }
        set {
            this["Test"] = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The problem with this is that any time you make a change to the Settings tab, you will have to go back into the designer.cs and change the type again.

Comment: yes of course. in my case I change it very rarely, and it's not a problem for me