# Null coalescing Operator on DateTime c#

Tags: c#, c#-6.0, c#-7.0

I personally like the [null coalescing Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) and I try to use it in my getters. But it seems to be restricted to certain Datatypes. 
For Instance following isn't building:

```
public DateTime From => Settings.Default.StartDate ?? DateTime.Today;
```

Error   CS0019  Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'DateTime' and 'DateTime'

and following is:

```
public DateTime From => Settings.Default.StartDate == null ? DateTime.Today : Settings.Default.StartDate;
```

Anybody has a clue why? Is it just not yet implemented or am I missing the logic here?

Comment: You might want to include the exact error message in the question

Comment: The second code compiles because it is nonsensical (since `Settings.Default.StartDate` will never be `null`) but technically valid (since you can compare anything to `null`). The first code is trying to protect you from that - it **knows** `StartDate` can't be `null` (since it is of type `DateTime`) - thus you are not allowed to use `??` on it.

Comment: DateTime isn't nullable, try: public DateTime? From =>

Comment: Possibly because the ?? only works on nullable types?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The null coalescing operator (`??`) only works if the expression to the left of the operator is nullable.

The error message:

> Error CS0019 Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type
>   'DateTime' and 'DateTime'

shows that `Settings.Default.StartDate` is not nullable - it is a `DateTime`.

As such, you need to change `StartDate` to be a **nullable** `DateTime` instead (i.e. `DateTime?`).

OK, but why then does:

```
public DateTime From => Settings.Default.StartDate == null ? DateTime.Today : Settings.Default.StartDate;
```

compile?

The short answer is that it is **nonsensical but technically valid**. The comparison to `null` will always be `false` (since a `DateTime` will never be `null`) and thus `Settings.Default.StartDate` will always be returned. It is just a convoluted way of writing:

```
public DateTime From => Settings.Default.StartDate;
```

So why doesn't `??` do the same thing? (i.e. let you use `??` when it doesn't really make sense to use it) Basically because it isn't defined that way - it doesn't want to allow you to do a nonsensical thing, so the compiler detects and blocks it.

Comment: Well it makes sense to me when you start the Program the first time and .. actually I don't know what value is in there if this is in the Settings file and I let the value empty and this is a not nullable Datatype

Comment: @k4yaman It **looks** to you like it is blank - but if you actually check its value (at runtime) it is actually 1 Jan 0001.

Comment: Since the Settings Editor Resets the Type of course and I didn't find the Type DateTime? to select i went with:
`public DateTime From => Settings.Default.EndDate == new DateTime() ? DateTime.Today : Settings.Default.EndDate;`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668030/nullable-int-type-allowed-in-settings-settings may also be worth a read @k4yaman.

Answer (score 1):

The DateTime type is a structure (not a class/reference type): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx